# Tailwind CSS table not applying styles

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-9

I'm currently learning basic Laravel and have already installed the laravel breeze  starter kit.

Currently trying to display a table but the tailwind CSS is not being applied to this table:

[image]

This is the code i've copied from the [tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/table-layout#basic-usage):

```
<table class="table-auto">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Song</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The Sliding Mr. Bones (Next Stop, Pottersville)</td>
      <td>Malcolm Lockyer</td>
      <td>1961</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Witchy Woman</td>
      <td>The Eagles</td>
      <td>1972</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shining Star</td>
      <td>Earth, Wind, and Fire</td>
      <td>1975</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've inserted the code into a blade file as below:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Cases') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                    
                    <table class="table-auto">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Song</th>
                            <th>Artist</th>
                            <th>Year</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td>The Sliding Mr. Bones (Next Stop, Pottersville)</td>
                            <td>Malcolm Lockyer</td>
                            <td>1961</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>Witchy Woman</td>
                            <td>The Eagles</td>
                            <td>1972</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>Shining Star</td>
                            <td>Earth, Wind, and Fire</td>
                            <td>1975</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

**webpack.mix.js** already has tailwindcss included as shown below:

[image]

I've also run `npm run dev`

What am I missing here?

Comment: does your project have a `/public/css/app.css` file ? are you using the `assets()` helper inside your templates ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've only specified how the table columns behave given the contents of each cell.  The style you've applied (`class="table-auto"` is occurring, but you don't notice it since the table width isn't being constrained by any parent element.

Make the screen narrower with the code as-is and you should see the long text in the first row start to wrap.

Additionally the documentation example only shows you the relevant class (`table-auto`) and not all the other styling.  Here's what's really being rendered:

```html
    <table class="border-collapse table-auto w-full text-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="border-b dark:border-slate-600 font-medium p-4 pl-8 pt-0 pb-3 text-slate-400 dark:text-slate-200 text-left">Song</th>
          <th class="border-b dark:border-slate-600 font-medium p-4 pt-0 pb-3 text-slate-400 dark:text-slate-200 text-left">Artist</th>
          <th class="border-b dark:border-slate-600 font-medium p-4 pr-8 pt-0 pb-3 text-slate-400 dark:text-slate-200 text-left">Year</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="bg-white dark:bg-slate-800">
        <tr>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-100 dark:border-slate-700 p-4 pl-8 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">The Sliding Mr. Bones (Next Stop, Pottersville)</td>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-100 dark:border-slate-700 p-4 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">Malcolm Lockyer</td>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-100 dark:border-slate-700 p-4 pr-8 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">1961</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-100 dark:border-slate-700 p-4 pl-8 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">Witchy Woman</td>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-100 dark:border-slate-700 p-4 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">The Eagles</td>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-100 dark:border-slate-700 p-4 pr-8 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">1972</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-200 dark:border-slate-600 p-4 pl-8 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">Shining Star</td>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-200 dark:border-slate-600 p-4 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">Earth, Wind, and Fire</td>
          <td class="border-b border-slate-200 dark:border-slate-600 p-4 pr-8 text-slate-500 dark:text-slate-400">1975</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```